# Add new node to an existing standalone solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a Solr indexing system on my local server that is currently working on one Hard drive only( one node). The hard drive is nearly full and I need to add a new drive to the Solr to make it work on two drives (nodes). I found only documentation on how to add new nodes in the CouldSolr. Are there any step by step guidelines on how to add new drive to an existing local Solr system and make it work on both drives?

Comment: You'll have to run two separate instances (you can probably do it with just two cores, but take the opportunity to run separate instances) and use manual sharding: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/distributed-search-with-index-sharding.html - otherwise you're looking at doing it on the operating system level by doing raid0 in a software raid instead (and reindexing after changing it).

Comment: I read that it's recommended to keep it one shard with multiple instances when working on local server, does using manual sharding means that we will have multiple shards?

Comment: I don't, but be aware that running disks in raid0 will lose the content if either disk fails. Running two separate instances and using the `shards` parameter will leave you with half your index if it should fail; which one of these are acceptable will depend on how quickly you can get everything up and running again. If you don't want to spend any time with either of these, use a disk that is large enough to keep 3x the current index size and with expected growth.

Comment: One replicated shard means that you have _the same index_ on multiple nodes. Having multiple shards means that the complete index is spread out over many cores. The first use case won't do anything useful in this case if your index is too large to fit on a single disk.

Comment: Thanks again. I found it bizzare that there is no documentation on how to do such obvious task. It looks like Solr lacks a lot of support

Comment: Manual sharding is just that. It's a limitation shared by most Lucene implementations (and most database systems); the server has a single data location. You either have multiple servers (sharding) or you configure the underlying storage as a single entity. SolrCloud was introduced with Solr4 back in 2012 and supports easily adding multiple new nodes.

Comment: Thanks again. Is the opposite to manual sharding the use of SolrCloud? Can I use SolrCloud with Zoopkeeper on my local server in my case?

Comment: Sure, that should work just fine. SolrCloud will handle everything automagically for you, start a new node with a new data directory and join it to the cluster.